# Visual studio. How to use search in disassembly window?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, disassembly

I want to find function in disassembly window using Ctrl+F by it's name (from symbols). How can I search through disassembly? Is there any extension?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think searching is possible. However, you can:

1) jump to an address if you know it (e.g. `0x76EC0B28`). Enter it in the `Address` field of the disassembly window.

2) jump to using mangled (decorated) name of the function (e.g. `_GetProcAddress@8`). Same as above.

3) add a breakpoint using the function name (New->Break at function... in the Breakpoints window), then use "Go to disassembly" from the context menu.

The last one possibly only works in VS2012 and above.